# Fetch Polyfill (whatwg-fetch) throws 'WebpackError: self is not defined'

Tags: reactjs, window, fetch, gatsby

Added whatwg-fetch to my Gatsby project `yarn add  whatwg-fetch`, but it no longer builds.

Instead, I receive the following error:

> ERROR #95313
>
> Building static HTML failed
>
> WebpackError: ReferenceError: self is not defined
>
> fetch.umd.js:8 
>    node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:8:1
>
> fetch.umd.js:2 
>    node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:2:63
>
> fetch.umd.js:5 Object../node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js
>    node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:5:2
>
> provider.js:1 Module../src/store/provider.js
>     src/store/provider.js:1:1
>
> gatsby-ssr.js:1 Module../gatsby-ssr.js
>     gatsby-ssr.js:1:1>

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think this is due to the window object being unavailable - it seems like this script was written to be run directly in the browser, rather than from the Gatsby/React context.

However, I found a workaround, which is to simply use a different polyfill called **fetchPonyfill**.

So I ran `yarn add fetch-ponyfill` to install. (For NPM users it would be `npm i fetch-ponyfill`)

...and then to import:
`import fetchPonyfill from 'fetch-ponyfill';`